# Mostrar Huella Dactilar en Picturebox

Tags: c#, sdk, huelladigital

Estoy desarrollando una funcionalidad que implica guardar la huella dactilar, para tal función he utilizado el lector `Digital Persona U 4500`.

Descargue e instale el SDK digital personal y genere una aplicacion windows form c#.

Añadi el control cuyo nombre: `DigitalPersona Fingerprint Enrollment Control` y en efecto captura la huella

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es poder visualizar la huella que se ha puesto en el lector para ver en detalle cómo ha quedado, para tal fin añadi un picturebox para que se mostrará en el y adicionalmente incluir lo siguiente:

```
 public DPFP.Sample Sample = new DPFP.Sample();// instancia la muestra


 DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion Convertor = new DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion(); 
 Bitmap bitmap = null;                                                              
 Convertor.ConvertToPicture(sample, ref bitmap);                                    
 PicBoxHuella.Image = bitmap;
```

Con la accion anterior deberia mostrar la muestra en el picture, pero no lo es asi.
Valido e identificado que el sample, llega en null.

No logro entender el valor Null, si al poner huella debería capturar el valor, les agradeceria orientarme un poco en el tema

> alguna idea de como recuperar el valor del sample?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sample esta en null porque estas creado una nueva instancia de Sample.
Creo que el valor que necesitas esta en ReaderSerialNumber, Tal vez Sample tenga una sobrecarga con ese parámetro o tengas que pasarlo en un método de Sample.